# SlimerJS extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled

Tags: node.js, casperjs, pm2, slimerjs

I'm having an issue running SlimerJS through CasperJS, I get the next message "**1414441945905  addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled"**.

I have a nodejs **scraper** running with CasperJS and Slimer (0.9.3) as the engine. This process is executed by another process (as a child_process.spawn). Also, this process is scheduled with PM2. It runs okay but sometime throws this error, and it hangs up, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had such error, to fix this you should add the line:

```
pref("extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled", true);
```

into your `*pref*.js` file. (in your firefox folder execute this:

```
nano `find ./ -name "*pref*.js"`
```

)
See for details: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=953998#c4